# Running a script ASAP on startup

Tags: boot

There are many other questions about running a script on startup, but I am specifically interested in getting a short Python script to run *as soon as possible* when the Pi boots.

All it requires is SPI to write to a TFT display (ILI9341). The screen is initially white, so I'd like to display something as soon as possible to appease the user. I'm running Raspbian Stretch on a RasPi 3 and it takes 16 seconds from when I connect power to when the script runs.

The script is in [/etc/init.d/MSDriver.sh](https://github.com/mindsensors/PiStorms/blob/master/setup/MSDriver.sh#L37), which runs a [show-logo.py](https://github.com/mindsensors/PiStorms/blob/master/programs/utils/show-logo.py#L30). Currently the [following](https://github.com/mindsensors/PiStorms/blob/master/setup/setup.sh#L177) is used to make it run on startup:

`sudo update-rc.d MSDriver.sh defaults 95 05`

**I've tried lowering `95` to `01`**, as from what I understand a lower number means a higher start priority. Even still, it takes 16 seconds from power-on to when the script runs.

Here's my LSB header: (I've prepended slashes only to stop raspi.SE from rendering them as headers)

`\#!/bin/sh
\### BEGIN INIT INFO
\# Provides:          MSDriver
\# Required-Start:    hostname $local_fs
\# Required-Stop:
\# Should-Start:
\# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
\# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
\# Short-Description: Start/stop MSDriver
\# Description:       This script starts/stops MSDriver.
\### END INIT INFO`

**How can I get this script to run sooner?**

(kindly let me know if there's anything I can do to improve my question, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might for starters use a systemd service file instead of a SysV style script, since those are supported for backward compatibility only (SysV is no longer used on most current linux distros, including Raspbian, so do not bother with online blogs etc. which reference it).  This will provide you with some more fine tuned control.  See in particular the *Before* and *After* clause in `man systemd.unit`:

> Before=, After=
>              A space-separated list of unit names. Configures ordering dependencies between units. If a unit foo.service contains a setting
>   Before=bar.service and both
>              units are being started, bar.service's start-up is delayed until foo.service is started up. Note that this setting is independent
>   of and orthogonal to the
>              requirement dependencies as configured by Requires=, Wants= or BindsTo=....

You might have a look at the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` for clues about what you want to to use in a "Before" clause; see `man systemd-analyze` for how to interpret the output.  A more detailed big picture is available with `systemd-anaylze plot` ([see here for an example of that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396269/25985)).

Examples of service files can be found in `/etc/systemd/system` and `/lib/systemd/system`; they are enabled/disabled/started/stopped etc. via `systemctl ...` (see `man systemctl`).